# What is BUCKET_ID in MediaStore?

Tags: android

I was browsing through some code that queries the MediaStore.Images content provider and uses a column named BUCKET_ID:

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
String projection[] = {
    "DISTINCT " + MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
};
String BUCKET_GROUP_BY = "1) GROUP BY 1,(2";
String BUCKET_ORDER_BY = "MAX(datetaken) DESC";
Cursor imagecursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, BUCKET_GROUP_BY, null, BUCKET_ORDER_BY);
```

In general, what do these columns represent? **Can anyone explain with examples?**(*The docs have a one-liner about these columns that explains quite less*)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Docs are vastly unclear on this and the above answer is a copy-paste from the docs. Anyway, I have found the answer from the [source of Gallery 3D](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.2.2_r1/com/android/gallery3d/data/BucketHelper.java) in form of comments:

```
    // BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME is a string like "Camera" which is the directory
    // name of where an image or video is in. BUCKET_ID is a hash of the path
    // name of that directory (see computeBucketValues() in MediaProvider for
    // details). MEDIA_TYPE is video, image, audio, etc.
    //
    // The "albums" are not explicitly recorded in the database, but each image
    // or video has the two columns (BUCKET_ID, MEDIA_TYPE). We define an
    // "album" to be the collection of images/videos which have the same value
    // for the two columns.
```

and here is the `computeBucketValues()` for reference:

```
/**
     * @param data The input path
     * @param values the content values, where the bucked id name and bucket display name are updated.
     *
     */
    private static void computeBucketValues(String data, ContentValues values) {
        File parentFile = new File(data).getParentFile();
        if (parentFile == null) {
            parentFile = new File("/");
        }

        // Lowercase the path for hashing. This avoids duplicate buckets if the
        // filepath case is changed externally.
        // Keep the original case for display.
        String path = parentFile.toString().toLowerCase();
        String name = parentFile.getName();

        // Note: the BUCKET_ID and BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME attributes are spelled the
        // same for both images and video. However, for backwards-compatibility reasons
        // there is no common base class. We use the ImageColumns version here
        values.put(ImageColumns.BUCKET_ID, path.hashCode());
        values.put(ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME**

added to API level 29
String BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME
The bucket display name of the image. This is a read-only property that is automatically computed from the DATA column.

Type: TEXT

Constant Value: "bucket_display_name"

**BUCKET_ID**

added in API level 29
String BUCKET_ID
The bucket id of the image. This is a read-only property that is automatically computed from the DATA column.

Type: TEXT

Constant Value: "bucket_id"

**DATE_TAKEN**

added to API level 29
String DATE_TAKEN
The date & time that the image was taken in units of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970.

Type: INTEGER

Constant Value: "datetaken"

Comment: This is copy paste from Docs!

Comment: Please add some explanation. As mentioned by Manish, this data is readily available in docs.