# MediaStore - BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME only present on API 29+?

Tags: android, mediastore, android-10.0

I was planning to query the MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME field, but Android Studio says it's only available on API 29+. Also, the [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns.html#BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME:kotlin.String) say the same.

However, I have found [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632774/what-is-bucket-id-in-mediastore) from 2017 when they used this same field.

What am I missing here?

Thank you.

EDIT: I also tried it on an Android 9.0 emulator and it works just fine.

Answer (score 10):

When looking at the [API diff](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/29-incr/changes) and the current [MediaStore source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/provider/MediaStore.java), we can see that until Android 10 (API 29), `BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME` was declared inside of `MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns`. On API 29 this property was moved to `MediaStore.MediaColumns` (which `MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns` implements), but the actual value of the constant it's the same.

So it seems it was simply moved to the parent interface, but its value is the same.

Comment: I wonder if Google is doing something to avoid confusions like this.

Comment: Thanks! We got similar case with `MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION` changed to `MediaStore.MediaColumns.ORIENTATION`. Did you find any clean solution for this?

Comment: I am facing a similar problem with `MediaStore.Audio.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME` Can anyone here help me please?